# Better way of querying NOTIN in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Using Spring Data JPA, I am using below jpa query (it works just fine) to query all the users except who is logged in (to get peers list).

```
appUserRepository.findByUsernameNotIn(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(getPrincipal()))).toString()
```

Since NotIn accepts collection only, and I had to filter-out just one name, I am using this 'clumsy' looking statement.

**Question:** Is there a better (short) way of achieving this? Meaning, getting all usernames from user table, except the logged-in user? Any clue/help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `findByUsernameNot(getPrincipal())`

This will create query like this:

```
… where x.username <> ?1
```

You can also check the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) for more information

Comment: Sweet.! great piece of info on the link and great answer (as expected -Short one). Never knew about "Not" have heard of only "NotIn". Thanks so much.